# Compare two array of objects and modify original array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let we have two array of objects as,

```
let oldArrayOfObject = [
    {
      Item: "ACC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "BCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "CCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "DCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "ECC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
  ];

let newArrayOfObject = [
  {
    Item: "ACC",
    Price: 12,
  },
  {
    Item: "BCC",
    Price: 50,
  },
  {
    Item: "ECC",
    Price: 21,
  }
];
```

Compare two array of objects and if price exists in newArrayOfObject for particular Item insert price into oldArrayOfObject for that particular item and set hasPrice: true.

Expected O/P:

```
console.log(oldArrayOfObject)

[
    {
      Item: "ACC",
      Price: 12,
      hasPrice: true,
    },
    {
      Item: "BCC",
      Price: 50,
      hasPrice: true,
    },
    {
      Item: "CCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "DCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "ECC",
      Price: 21,
      hasPrice: true,
    },
  ];
```

For this I tried as,

```
const modifiedArrayOfObject = newArrayOfObject.map((node) => {
  const oldInfo = oldArrayOfObject.find((item) => item.Item === node.Item);
  if (oldInfo) {
    return { ...node, hasPrice: oldInfo.Price !==  node.Price }
  } else {
     return { ...node, hasPrice: true };
  }
});
```

But I am unable to move forward from here. Please let me know if anyone needs any further explanation or further clearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code were

- You have to find the nodes from `oldArrayOfObject` in `newArrayOfObject`. Your `oldInfo` should be defined as `oldInfo = newArrayOfObject.find((item) => item.Item === node.Item);`
- Also if `oldInfo` is found, you should reurn the `Price` as `Price: oldInfo.Price`
- Incase if the `oldInfo` is not found, you have to return the current node itself. Dont set `hasPrice: true` manually in that.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const oldArrayOfObject = [{ Item: "ACC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "BCC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "CCC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "DCC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "ECC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }];

const newArrayOfObject = [{ Item: "ACC", Price: 12, }, { Item: "BCC", Price: 50, }, { Item: "ECC", Price: 21 }];

const modifiedArrayOfObject = oldArrayOfObject.map((node) => {
    const oldInfo = newArrayOfObject.find((item) => item.Item === node.Item);
    if (oldInfo) {
        return { ...node, Price: oldInfo.Price, hasPrice: oldInfo.Price !== node.Price }
    } else {
        return { ...node };
    }
});
console.log(modifiedArrayOfObject);
```

`Array.map` always create a new array from an existing array.

If you want to update the original array itself instead of creating a new array, you could run a loop on `oldArrayOfObject` and check if each node from `oldArrayOfObject` is there in `newArrayOfObject`. Then update `hasPrice` and `Price` if the matching node is found.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const oldArrayOfObject = [{ Item: "ACC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "BCC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "CCC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "DCC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }, { Item: "ECC", Price: "", hasPrice: false, }];

const newArrayOfObject = [{ Item: "ACC", Price: 12, }, { Item: "BCC", Price: 50, }, { Item: "ECC", Price: 21 }];

oldArrayOfObject.forEach((node) => {
    const oldInfo = newArrayOfObject.find((item) => item.Item === node.Item);
    if (oldInfo) {
        node.hasPrice = oldInfo.Price !== node.Price;
        node.Price = oldInfo.Price;
    }
});
console.log(oldArrayOfObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this function in example:

```js
let oldArrayOfObject = [
    {
      Item: "ACC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "BCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "CCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "DCC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
    {
      Item: "ECC",
      Price: "",
      hasPrice: false,
    },
  ];

let newArrayOfObject = [
  {
    Item: "ACC",
    Price: 12,
  },
  {
    Item: "BCC",
    Price: 50,
  },
  {
    Item: "ECC",
    Price: 21,
  }
];

function modifiedArrayOfObject(item) {
   newArrayOfObject.map(v => {
    if(v.Item === item){
      const index = oldArrayOfObject.findIndex(obj => obj.Item === v.Item);
      oldArrayOfObject[index] = { Item: v.Item, Price: v.Price, hasPrice: true };
    }
   })
 console.log("oldArrayOfObject:", oldArrayOfObject)
}
modifiedArrayOfObject("ACC")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to modify `oldArrayOfObject` then I would not suggest using `map` for this. Instead use a simple `for` loop -

```js
const oldArrayOfObject = ...

const newArrayOfObject = ...

for (const t of newArrayOfObject) {
  const q = oldArrayOfObject.find(o => o.Item=== t.Item)
  if (q == null) continue
  q.Price = t.Price
  q.hasPrice = true
}

console.log(oldArrayofObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse **newArrayOfObjects** and **oldArrayOfObjects**. This is solution for your way:

```
const modifiedArrayOfObject = oldArrayOfObject.map((node) => {
    const newInfo = newArrayOfObject.find((item) => item.Item === node.Item);
    if (newInfo) return { ...node, hasPrice: true, Price: newInfo.Price };
    return node;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to change any of the arrays, leave them immutable and create a new array unifying them. You were on the right track, however, as your oldest list has more items, you should go through it instead of the new one, and if that scenario changes, your code would break.

```
const modifiedArrayOfObject = oldArrayOfObject.map((oldInfo) => {
  const newInfo = newArrayOfObject.find((newInfo) =>  newInfo.Item === oldInfo.Item);
  if (newInfo && newInfo.Price) {
    return { ...oldInfo, Price: newInfo.Price, hasPrice: true };
  }

  return { ...oldInfo, hasPrice: false };
});


console.log("modifiedArrayOfObject:", modifiedArrayOfObject);
```

Also, don't use map without return.